# dhcpcd display all responses

Tags: dhcp

I want to watch my network for DHCP servers, so I use `dhcpcd -T $interface` to dump the response of the DHCP server. How do I tell `dhcpcd` to display *all* the responses (normally the official dhcp server is the fastest one but I want to capture for other, slower ones)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need something like `tcpdump` or (better) [`dhcpdump`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-dhcpdump-monitor-dhcp-traffic/) for this.